# How to disconnect a network on Android Q?

Tags: android, networking, android-10.0

According to documentation if we remove the network suggestion list, the system will disconnect from that network, but it doesn't work.

```
int statusCode = wifiManager.removeNetworkSuggestions(new ArrayList<>());
```

Here I'm removing all the networks suggested by our app, the status code is **WifiManager.STATUS_NETWORK_SUGGESTIONS_SUCCESS** but the network is not actually disconnected.

Comment: Hey, I currently have the same problem and I was wondering if you found a fix.

Comment: Hey, no... I'm just calling wifiManager.removeNetworkSuggestions(new ArrayList<>())

Comment: Ah, that's too bad. I ended up just leaving a message saying that the user should disable then re-enable their Wifi to disconnect from it.

Comment: @Raluca did you manage to found any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The way to connect to a Wifi accessory is by using the ConnectivityManager with a call to `connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback`.

After doing your stuff with the connection (accessory) you can call `connectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback` to disconnect from it.